# Sharepoint File Modification History

Tags: sharepoint, edit, history

So I moved around certain files and folders in Sharepoint.

Is there a way to figure out where the files etc were stored previously? 
(I need to move some back to their original path)

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't. This is not a developer question, so it's offtopic at this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you kept the original files in the original document libraries, there's no way to tell where a file used to reside.  Another option is to use audit logs to see when and where a file was deleted (assuming you deleted it when you moved the file to it's new location.

Comment: Ya Guess will have to do it from now on.